# Convert postgres JSON to rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Having a JSON column with contents `{"1":[1,2,3], "2":[0]}`, is it possible to convert that to rows? Such as:

```
|id|sub_id|
| 1|     1|
| 1|     2|
| 1|     3|
| 2|     0|
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
WITH expand AS (
  SELECT
    json_object_keys(json) AS key,
    json
  FROM table
)

SELECT
  key,
  json_array_elements(json->key)
FROM expand
```